# Is there any alternative for AppCenter for mobile testing in Azure DevOps?

Tags: appium, devops

I am new to mobile testing, and using Appium for my tests. We are using Azure Devops. Since our team is relatively small and there's no really budget for QA, I am looking to see if there's any way I can run my automated test with Azure DevOps without the use of VSTS or App Center?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about the answer,But cant you host a jenkins server on you local PC and run the test cases using MS test runner? 
Jenkins is free,MS test is also free if you go for VS community edition.

Comment: I am looking into Jenkins too. but I was thinking if I can use a Jenkins task to get to the Azure. We are doing DevOps, I am pretty new to it and I am not sure about how our test codes will be set up. If I don't see anything other than Jenkins, then I'd go for Jenkins

Comment: DevOps is free up to some extent, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here are some alternative solutions available for running Appium tests in Azure DevOps without using App Center:

1. Selenium Grid: You can set up a Selenium Grid infrastructure on Azure DevOps using Azure VMs or Azure Container Instances. This will allow you to run your Appium tests in parallel on multiple devices or emulators.
2. Azure DevOps hosted agents: You can also use Azure DevOps hosted agents to run your Appium tests. Hosted agents provide a pre-configured environment with all the necessary tools and dependencies installed, including Appium, Java, and other required libraries.
3. On-premises agents: If you have on-premises infrastructure, you can install Azure DevOps agents on those machines and use them to run your tests.
4. Third-party cloud-based services: There are several cloud-based services that offer testing infrastructure and allow you to run Appium tests, including Sauce Labs, BrowserStack, and Perfecto. These services offer a wide range of devices and environments, and they integrate with Azure DevOps.